# Proving Assymptotic tight bound on $\lg(n!)$ is equivalent to $n\lg(n)$ without using Stirling's Approximation.

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, upper-lower-bounds, stirling-numbers

So, how I did it is by expanding  $f(n)=\lg(n!)$ to first
\begin{align}
\lg(n!) &= \lg(n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot2\cdot 1)\\
 &=\lg(n)+\lg(n-1)+\lg(n-2)+...+\lg(1)\\
  n\lg(n) &\geq  \lg(n)+\lg(n-1)+\lg(n-2)+...+\lg(1)
\end{align}
thus, $f(n) =  O(n\lg(n))$.

Then
\begin{align}
f(n) &= \lg(n)+\lg(n-1)+\ldots+\lg(n/2)+\lg(n/2-1)+...\lg(1)\\
\lg(n)+\lg(n-1)+\ldots+\lg(n/2+1)  &\geq n/2\lg(n/2)\\
f(n) &\geq n/2\lg(n/2)
\end{align}
and thus   $f(n) = Ω(n/2\lg(n/2)) \Rightarrow  f(n) =  Ω(n\lg(n))$

as,  $f(n) = O(n\lg(n))$ ,   $f(n)= Ω(n\lg(n)$,
$f(n) = \Theta(n\lg(n))$

Is this would be the correct way of proving $f(n)=\Theta(n\lg(n))$,  where $f(n)=\lg(n!)$ without using Stirling's Approximation.

Comment: Can you check that after my corrections everything is ok now?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your derivation is correct. Well done!